# XMPP Error When Retrieving Roster ('No module is handling this query')

Tags: reactjs, xml, xmpp, ejabberd

I am using an ejabberd server. ejabberd supports RFC-6121 (see https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/protocols/). And RFC-6121 should allow me to request a roster from the server through sending an xml formatted as follows (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121.html#section-2.1.3):

```
<iq from='juliet@example.com/balcony'
          id='bv1bs71f'
          type='get'>
     <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/>
</iq>
```

I am sending the following xml (using React, TypeScript, import '@xmpp/client')

```
function requestRoster() {
    return xmppClient?.send(
        xml('iq', {from: 'User1@tutor', id: '12345678', type: 'get'},
            xml('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'})
        )
    );
}
```

However, the server responds with an  stanza containing an error. It says: 'No module is handling this query' and 'service-unavailable'. Why? This should work and be really simple. But I have been working on it for quite a while...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/arablinda/b699f84bd814622f222a8a75b6fa5325

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was thinking that an ejabberd server comes, by default, with all the functionality listed here https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/protocols/. However, ejabberd is based on a modular system. You have to add modules to access certain functionality. In our case, a module called 'mod_roster' which implements the RFC6121 protocol which allows roster management. You can simply add modules through changing the ejabberd.yml file.